# PDO Get Multiple Insert Ids 

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, pdo, last-insert-id

Running the following query using PDO (Actually, I use prepared statements but same problem)

`INSERT INTO MyTable(MyField) VALUES('Row1'), ('Row2')`

How can I get the Ids for the records relating to `Row1` and `Row2`?

`$db->lastInsertId()` literally returns the last single Id.

Is it sufficient to take this last Id, subtract the # of records and assume that range covers all my records? can there be gaps/jumps. Is this query guaranteed to be atomic?

Comment: Which storage engine are you using? InnoDB? MyISAM?

Comment: It's currently MyISAM but I'm hoping to use InnoDb in future so exporting the schema includes the FK constraints. That said, I can be flexible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using MyISAM tables then because of the table level locking mechanism it's only possible for you to get given a range of ids.

After reading http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html#innodb-auto-increment-traditional assuming you're using "traditional" innodb locking (which likely you are) then again for a single statement the set of IDs will be sequential.

Comment: thanks for the response, can you please clarify - Table-level locking (whilst normally bad) might be a boon in this scenario but the PHP lastInsertId() function returns only a single Id even if multiple records are inserted.

Comment: if you insert ten rows then the range of ids you just inserted will be `LAST_INSERT_ID() - 10` - `LAST_INSERT_ID()`