# PDO - Retrieving a variable value from a transaction?

Tags: php, mysql, database, transactions, pdo

Given the following block of code:

```
$q = "
BEGIN;
DECLARE User_ID int
INSERT INTO user (field1,field2) values (value1,value2);
set User_ID = select LAST_INSERT_ID();
INSERT INTO table2 (field1,field2) values (value1,LAST_INSERT_ID());
select User_ID
COMMIT;";

$sth = PDO::prepare($q);
$sth->execute();
```

How the heck to do I retreive the value "User_ID" ? fetch and fetchAll just return empty arrays, and there are no errors thrown in the process

**EDIT 1** Sorry, should have been more clear... there is a second INSERT statement before returning the results.

Answer (score 1):

$q = "
BEGIN;
DECLARE User_ID int
INSERT INTO user (field1,field2) values (value1,value2);
set User_ID = select LAST_INSERT_ID();
INSERT INTO table2 (field1,field2) values (value1,LAST_INSERT_ID() - 1);
select User_ID
COMMIT;";

$sth = PDO::prepare($q);
$sth->execute();

Comment: Providing your engine supports it

Comment: sorry, should have been more clear... there is a second INSERT clause prior to returning the user_id... hence setting the variable value rather than just grabbing it with PDO's version.

Comment: OK you will need to use a transaction then

Comment: try looking at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5941275/pdo-get-multiple-insert-ids-php5

Comment: Hmm... yea i'm still trying to find a transaction solution. I'll probably end up doing it in two stages for the time being, I think I just need to do some reading on PDO transactions and see if I find my answer there. Thanks for your help!